# Google Geocoding API - Do commas matter when building an address to geocode?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) to geocode some addresses and while I found the [guideline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding) on building addresses to send, I couldn't find anything on the use of commas (or any delimiter for that matter) to separate the street address from the city, state, country, and postal code.

Using this address as an example: 
3501 W Lake Rd 
Abilene, Texas, United States 79601

You can build the url without using any commas:

[`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3501+W+Lake+Rd+Abilene+Texas+United+States+79601`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3501%20W%20Lake%20Rd%20Abilene%20Texas%20United%20States%2079601)

Or you can build it with some commas to separate the name of the street from everything else. 
[`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3501+W+Lake+Rd,+Abilene,+Texas+United+States+79601`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=3501%20W%20Lake%20Rd,%20Abilene,%20Texas%20United%20States%2079601)

Both seem to return the same response. The addition of commas don't have any effect on the response.

Are there cases where commas affect the response from Google? Or does it really not matter?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google's API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding) the addresses should be:

> in the format used by the national postal service of the country
>   concerned

Which would include commas, at least in the US. I think it just depends on the address on if it will have issues and will also depend on what gets sent to Google, such as whether `st.` or `street` is added to the end or not, which could help google figure out where the street part ends and the city part begins, but that is just a guess.

Comment: I saw that you should use the format of the country you're geocoding for. I dug this up on the [USPS site](http://pe.usps.com/text/dmm100/addressing-mail.htm) on addressing after I read your answer. It says that you should not use commas at least when addressing an envelope by hand. I guess my takeaway is to just adhere to the standards of the country?

Comment: @Cuthbert Interesting. I wonder if they say that because when you write out an address you usually go to the next line instead of adding a comma but then again you would still normally add a comma between the city and state. Strange! Either way, yes, I think you are right that the standards of the country should be followed.

Comment: Lies my teacher told me? https://brokensecrets.com/2010/05/04/punctuation-is-not-allowed-in-mailing-addresses/ and http://pe.usps.gov/text/pub28/28c2_007.htm?q=punctuation&t=H&s=R&p=1&c=Pub28

Comment: @Cuthbert What in the world! Haha thats crazy. Guess commas really are not necessary then. Thanks for the links